# create a facebook style status update box with css?

Tags: css, callout

I've been looking all over the internet for a tutorial on how to create a facebook style status update css box. It's the current facebook status update callout box, it's square with a little noch at the top.

Can anyone help me put together a css design for something like this please?

Thanks

Example:

```
________^_____________________
|                             |
|                             |
|                             |
|_____________________________|
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [this demo](http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-speech-bubbles/demo/), it lists many many kinds of "boxes with arrows".